# display data from the array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, codeigniter-3

Having 3 columns in the table where all the column values are stored in array.
this is my table

```
id   bill_id         description               quantity             amount

16    16           ["item1","item2","item3"]     ["2","1","2"]      ["100","100","150"]
```

and this is my code to view the result

```
    <?php $description=json_decode($result->description)?>
    <?php $amount=json_decode($result->amount)?>
    <?php $quantity=json_decode($result->quantity);?>
       <?php foreach($description as $row){?>
       <tr class="item-row">


       <td class="description"><textarea class="textarea" name="description[]"><?php echo $row;?></textarea></td>
       <td><textarea name="amount[]" class="cost textarea"><?php echo $amount;?></textarea></td>
       <td><textarea name="quantity[]" class="qty textarea"><?php echo $quantity;?></textarea></td>

      <td><span class="price"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <?php }?>
```

i want to see my result like this while using foreach

```
            description        amount           quantity
             item1               2               100
             item2               1               100
             item3               2               150
```

if i give foreach for amount and quantity the result is coming repeatedly

Comment: If the all 3 arrays are indexed the same, you can then access it directly by index in one foreach/for loop like `$amount[$index]` and $quantity[$index]`.

Comment: but can we give 3 values in a single foreach loop

Comment: Yes, you can do `foreach($description as $index => $row){ echo $row; echo $amount[$index]; echo $quantity[$index]; }` for all 3 values but you need to mind that all 3 arrays have to be indexed the same.

Comment: thanks a lot now i understood...